# Explanation of the first step in the proof of Vitali theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation

The theorem and the first part of its proof is given below:

> [image]

But I do not understand the first statement in the proof, why countable subadditivity of outer measure lead us to suppose that $E$ is bounded? could anyone explain this for me, please?

Comment: Because one of $E\cap [n,n+1)$ for $n\in\mathbb Z$ will have positive outer measure

Comment: And what is the relation with countable subadditivity in this case @Wojowu

Comment: @Smart If each $E\cap [n,n+1)$ had outer measure zero, then by countable subadditivity $E$ would have outer measure zero.

Comment: thanks! got it :) @Wojowu

Comment: I am sorry, I am not fully convinced , do you represent $E$ when it is unbounded by $E \cap [n, n+1)$ ? (if so, it is unusual because usually the intersection give us the smaller set )@Wojowu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Theorem 17: Any set of real numbers with positive outer measure contains a subset that fails to be measurable.

Theorem 17': Any bounded set of real numbers with positive outer measure contains a subset that fails to be measurable.

The part of the proof that follows the first sentence proves theorem 17'. We therefore just have to deduce theorem 17 from theorem 17'.

Deduction of theorem 17 from theorem 17': Let $E$ be a set of real numbers with positive outer measure. Let $\mu$ denote outer measure. If $\mu(E \cap [n,n+1)) = 0$ for each $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $\mu(E) = \mu(\cup_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} E\cap [n,n+1) ) \le \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \mu(E\cap [n,n+1)) = 0$, a contradiction. In other words, there is some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $\mu(E\cap [n,n+1)) > 0$. Applying theorem 17' to $E \cap [n,n+1)$ (which we may, since $\mu(E\cap[n,n+1)) > 0$ and since $E \cap [n,n+1) \subseteq [n,n+1)$ is bounded), we get some non-measurable set $F \subseteq E\cap [n,n+1)$. Since $F$ is then a non-measurable subset of $E$ as well, theorem 17 is deduced.